# Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSArray * from User *

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, return-value

I'm beginner in iOS programming and I need some help with returning array from function.
I have this structure of my application(I don't if it's correct):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/md4b2nrdf09wdny/Screenshot%202014-02-28%2018.11.30.png

User.h/.m are files generated from CoreData model and have 4 property.

LoginVC.h/.m is using for log in to application (authorization).

UserController is using for work with user structure - save user, update user, get all users etc.

What I need...I have function in UserController.m the function looks like this:

```
-(NSArray *)getUsers{

    CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] cdh];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];

    NSArray *Users = [cdh.context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    return Users;

}
```

The function is for getting all users from table User and return Array of users.

I would like to call this function in LoginVC.m, so I push this code to function viewDidLoad:

```
UserController *userController = [[UserController alloc]init];

[userController getUsers];
NSArray *users = [[NSArray alloc]init];

users = [userController getUsers];
```

But when I start application there is a error or warning - Incomaptible pointer types assigning to NSArray* from User* and I don't know why is the realy problem, because function getAllUsers return Array and I assign to Array. Thank you for help.

Comment: Can we see the declaration of getUsers from UserController.h?

Comment: Your second batch of code seems redundant. The bottom three lines can be consolidated into `NSArray *users = [userController getUsers];`. That could possibly fix your problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No need to alloc/init users and then set it to the returned value of [userController getUsers]. If you are using arc, you are good to go just to do like so: NSArray *users = [userController getUsers], but if you aren't using arc, just throw a retain on the end of [userController getUsers].

Comment: I should note, that WON'T fix the issue…see the answers below for the fix. But it WILL be correctly written if you follow my suggestion above.

Comment: What exactly is an "arc" please? The allocation is performed automatically, when I assign the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any `User *` in the code you posted, but I think the only logical explanation for the compiler warning is that `getUsers` is declared in `UserController.h` as `- (User *)getUsers` instead of `- (NSArray *)getUsers`.

Comment: Thanks to both. I'm sorry the error was really in UserController.h. I have there (User *) instead of (NSArray *). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Coloration is giving you a tips.

Rename your variable `Users` to `users` on line :

```
NSArray *Users = [cdh.context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Comment: This does not solve his problem. The case of the variable name is irrelevant. Stack Overflow is coloring it as a class name because normally class names are uppercase. It is still a valid variable name, though.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr Colors aside, this answer could be relevant. There could possibly be a class by the name of User that is causing the issue.

Comment: Even if there was it would not cause the error he's experiencing. His error has to do with pointer coercion.